# If the application icon is disabled using PackageManager, will it cause issue in auto update of that app?

Tags: android

I have a application in which the app icon is hidden using following code:

```
 PackageManager p = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager(); 
      p.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(),PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
 PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Will this cause an issue in updating the application (when a new version is uploaded in play store)? And if yes, is there any workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is No, there will not be any issues. The application will be updated successfully. I can confirm this as I have implemented this in one of my application and I observed the application was updated without any issues.